# Grep on macOS: find unique occurrences of a capturing group in regular expression

Tags: macos, regex, grep, uniq

I am on macOS and would like to get into using `grep` (or a similar tool) to find unique occurrences of a certain pattern in a codebase. For example, for finding all `console.somemethod()` calls in JavaScript I have devised:

```
grep -oiER "console\.([a-z]+)\(" . | sort -u
```

But this gets me results in the form:

```
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn/src/bin/acorn.js:console.log(
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/wordwrap/README.markdown:console.log(
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/wordwrap/example/center.js:console.log(
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/wordwrap/example/meat.js:console.log(
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/yargs/README.md:console.dir(
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/yargs/README.md:console.log(
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/yargs/index.js:console.log(
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js:console.error(
./tools/svg-inject/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js:console.log(
./webpack.config.js:console.info(
Console.sendTo(
console.error(
console.log(
console.markTimeline(
console.reactStackEnd(
console.timeEnd(
console.trace(
console.warn(
```

I would like to restrict it to unique matches of the `([a-z]+)` group **only**:

```
info
sendTo
error
log
markTimeline
reactStackEnd
timeEnd
trace
warn
```

Apologies if I'm rehashing an old question!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Oops, added the expected result to the question.

Comment: Normally, I'd use `sed` for this sort of thing, but it works only with a specific file list (no `-R` option). You can pipe the existing `grep` output through `sed`, but this gives no advantage over piping through `perl` or a second `grep`, as in @Toto's answer. If you know the depth of the directory tree, you can use `sed -n 's/^.*console\.\([a-z]+\)(.*$/\1/p' * */* */*/* */*/*/*|sort -u` (for three levels of subdirectory). It's worth getting to know `sed`, and [this](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html) is a good introduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-P` option for perl regex with `\K` directive in the regex that will exclude the preceding string part matching from the result:

```
grep -ioP "console\.\K[a-z]+" file.txt
log
log
log
log
dir
log
log
error
log
info
sendTo
error
log
markTimeline
reactStackEnd
timeEnd
trace
warn
```

I have put your example lines in file.txt to test.

To restrict to uniq occurrence:

```
grep -ioP "console\.\K[a-z]+" file.txt | sort -u
dir
error
info
log
markTimeline
reactStackEnd
sendTo
timeEnd
trace
warn
```

**Another solution** `-P` option has been remove macOS version `10.8`

If you have perl installed:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /console\.([a-z]+)/' file.txt | sort -u
dir
error
info
log
mark
react
time
trace
warn
```

In order to work with all files in the directory:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /console\.([a-z]+)/' * | sort -u
```

Comment: oof, I forgot to mention I'm on macOS and the command doesn't seem to work (it may be missing the `-P` flag).

Comment: @Dan: See my edit edit, it should work if you have perl installed

Comment: Aah, almost there! Is there any chance it will work recursively in the current folder to match all files?

Comment: This is the final, glorious form: `find . -exec perl -nle 'print $1 if /console\.([a-z]+)\(/i' {} + | sort -u`

Comment: @Dan: Or course, change `file.txt` to `*`

Comment: (I had tried with `./**/*.js` but I got the `argument list too long` error)

Comment: @Dan: You're welcome, glad it helps.